# Set column value on Sheet 2 to true when criteria is met

Tags: google-apps-script

Disclaimer: New to scripting...When the value of a cell column A on Sheet 1 matches column C on Sheet 2, another column on Sheet 2(same row) is updated with "true".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm not sure if you want column A and column C match on the same row (e.g. `A3=C3`) or not (e.g. `A1=C2`), I have provided both possibility in the script below. See output for their difference and use either one of them depending on your case.

#### Script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var sheet1ColA = sheet1.getRange('A:A').getValues().flat().filter(String);
  var sheet2ColC = sheet2.getRange('C:C').getValues().flat().filter(String);
  // assuming the column we would like to update is Sheet2!D:D
  var sheet2ColD = sheet2.getRange('D:D').getValues().flat().filter(String);

  // if Sheet1ColA = Sheet2ColC and should be in the same row
  // e.g. Sheet1!A3 = Sheet2!C3
  var output = sheet2ColD.map((row, index) => [sheet2ColC[index] == sheet1ColA[index] ? true : row]);
  
  // if Sheet1ColA is present in Sheet2ColC regardless of the row
  // e.g. Sheet1!A1 = Sheet2!C2
  var output = sheet2ColD.map((row, index) => [sheet1ColA.includes(sheet2ColC[index]) ? true : row]);
  
  sheet2.getRange(1, 4, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
}
```

#### Sheet1:

[image: sheet1]

#### Sheet2:

[image: sheet2]

#### Output (same row):

```
var output = sheet2ColD.map((row, index) => [sheet2ColC[index] == sheet1ColA[index] ? true : row]);
```

[image: output1]

#### Output (regardless of row):

```
var output = sheet2ColD.map((row, index) => [sheet1ColA.includes(sheet2ColC[index]) ? true : row]);
```

[image: output2]

#### Update:

- If you want to change the values of Sheet2!D:D every time Sheet1!A:A is edited, then you will need to use `onEdit` which triggers the function when a manual edit is done (e.g. editing the cell).

#### Script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if(sheet.getName() == 'Sheet1' && range.getColumn() == 1) {
    myFunction();
  }
}

function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var sheet1ColA = sheet1.getRange('A:A').getValues().flat().filter(String);
  var sheet2ColC = sheet2.getRange('C:C').getValues().flat().filter(String);

  // for removed data that previously match, overwrite with false
  var output = sheet2ColC.map((row, index) => [sheet1ColA.includes(sheet2ColC[index]) ? true : false]);
  
  sheet2.getRange(1, 4, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The version with "Output (regardless of row)" works. Is there a way to set the D column "true" after the criteria is met and only once?

Comment: it should be possible. You need to add an additional condition that checks whether how many of that element is in the array. It will look like this: 

```var output = sheet2ColD.map((row, index) => [sheet1ColA.includes(sheet2ColC[index]) && sheet1ColA.filter(cell => cell == sheet2ColC[index]).length == 1 ? true : row]);```. basically, the conditions here is that it will turn into `TRUE` if the value in Sheet1!A is in Sheet2!C and there is only 1 value of that in Sheet1!A.

Comment: Hi @MarcEli, If the posted answer above worked, please click the accept button on the left part of the answer (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. The goal is to check "true" on Sheet 2 Column D every time  Sheet  1 Column A is updated  and matches Sheet 2 Column C.

Comment: I have modified my answer and added the `Update` section. Kindly check. @MarcEli

Comment: I get an error:  
TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined

Comment: You do not need to run the script. Just save it and edit Sheet1!A:A then check Sheet2!D:D. it will automatically adjust whenever Sheet1!A:A is edited as I mentioned in the answer. @MarcEli

Comment: Sorry to say it is not working

Comment: Have you tried debugging the script? Check the execution logs to see what's the issue.

Comment: Tried that also. Says 'undefined'

Comment: I have modified the script. See sample sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q3Xb57wI1ulvrM6rnbNS2yr5saGmcNMW_V6L6VsLCTQ/edit#gid=0

Comment: This is close to working as expected. Some rows are "true" that should not be because there is not a corresponding entry in Sheet 1. And some that should be "true" with corresponding entry are not. Also. It should ignore all other entries except new ones

Comment: Provide a sample sheet you are working as that script is working fine on my side. There are edits on the sheet I've given that is inputting values into wrong columns. @MarcEli

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to use a formula:

```
=IF(EQ(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!C1),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Just put it into any cell in row 1 and you will get `TRUE` if `A1` == `C1` or `FALSE` otherwise. If you copy it on another row, you will get result for the cells of that another row.